# mysql database with revolving data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure the best way to phrase this question!

I have a mysql database that needs to retrieve and store the past 24 data values, and the data always needs to be the last 24 data values.

I have this fully working, but I am sure there must be a better way to do it!

Just now, my mysql database has columns for id, timestamp, etc, and then 24 data columns:

```
data_01
data_02
data_03
data_04
data_05
etc
```

There are multiple rows for different ids.

I run a cron job every hour, which deletes column 'data_24', and then renames all columns:

```
data_01 -> data_02
data_02 -> data_03
data_03 -> data_04
data_04 -> data_05
data_05 -> data_06
etc
```

And then adds a new, blank column:

```
data_01
```

The new data is then added into this new, blank column.

Does this sound like a sensible way to do this, or is there any better way??

My concern with this method is that the column deleting, renaming and adding has to be done first, before the new data is retrieved, so that the new column exists for adding data.

If the data retrieve fails for any reason, my table then has a column with NULL as a data value.

Comment: Cant you use a view of your total table which just collects the last 24 records using LIMIT?

Comment: You mean always collect and store the data, and only view the last 24? This would get out of hand very quickly, collecting so much data. I only ever need the last 24, so keeping ALL data is a waste.

Comment: Where do you get the data for the data_01 that is then updated/inserted?  you could just do a self join and roll the data from data_24=data_23 and so on. and update data_01 to passed in value.  Horizontal store more challenging than vertical.

Comment: Just use the last 24 data in a view. Define your own deletion timeframe independently. 1 hour, 1 day, 1 min. define it as per your own requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming columns for something like this is not a good idea.

I'm curious how you insert and update this data, but there must be a better way to do this.

Two things that seem feasible:

Not renaming the column, but moving the data to the next column:

```
  update YourTable 
  set data1 = :newvalue, 
      data2 = data1, 
      data3 = data2, 
      ...;
```

Or by spreading the data over 24 rows instead of having 24 columns. Each data is a row in your table, (or in a new table where your id is a foreign key). Every time when you insert a new value, you can also delete the oldest value for that same id. You can do this in one atomic transaction so there won't ever be more or less than 24 rows per id.

```
insert into YourTable(id, data) 
values (:id, :newvalue);

delete from YourTable
where id = :id
order by timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

This will multiply the number of rows (but not the amount of data) by 24, so for 1000 rows (like you mentioned), you're talking about 24000 rows, which is still peanuts if you have the proper indexes.

We got tables in MySQL with over 100 million rows. Manipulating 24000 rows is WAY easier than rewriting a complete table of 1000 rows, which is essentially what you're doing by renaming the columns.

So the second option certainly has my preference. It will provide you with a simple structure, and should you ever decide to not clean up old data, or move that to a separate job, or stick to 100 items instead of 24, then you can easily do that by changing 3 lines of code, instead of completely overhauling your table structure and the application with it.

Comment: I have over 1000 rows in the table, so the best way is to have the 24 data entries as the columns. New data is retrieved from a JSON call from an API. The ids are fixed, so I just insert new data to the column 'data_01' using an UPDATE WHERE id='id' command.

Comment: You're welcome to select my first suggestion, but please do note that 24000 rows is still peanuts for MySQL, and is way easier than actually modifying the table (which will force MySQL to create a temp table in the background, move all the data around, rename table, delete old table)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as a sensible way of doing thins, to be honest.

IMHO, having multiple rows instead of having the wide table is much more flexible.

You can define columns (id, entity_id, created). Then you'll be able to write your records in a "log" manner.

When you need to select the data in the same way as it used to be, you can use the MySQL view for that. Something like

```
  CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
  SELECT data_01, ..., data_24   -- here you should put the aggregated values aliased as data_01 ... data_24
  FROM my_table 
  WHERE my_table.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  GROUP BY ... -- here you should aggregate the fields by hours
  ORDER BY created;
```